# vba Insert jpg to specific cells by matching cell value with image name

Tags: excel, image, macos, vba, insert

I've looked around on a few different ways to insert .jpg by a macro and there seem to be few, but some different ways. I tried to follow [this](http://ccm.net/faq/6485-excel-a-macro-to-insert-pictures) helpful guide, but are unsuccessful.

MY macro doesn't find the image location. I want the macro to look for images saved in a folder named "Pictures" in the same location the current workbook, compare it to references in column A and insert in column B if match.

I get this error message: "Unable to get the insert property of the Pictures class." Does mean my link is wrong?

As you can see ([Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY5VJ.png)) my references are in Column A, starting at A7, but I have merged cells(A7:A16), so the next reference is in A18, A29.. etc. 
ex.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
Sub ImageMacro()

'Used to import picture files from a pre-sorted file. (Each picture must have a unique name, duplicates removed).

'Sub Picture()
 Dim picname As String
 Dim pasteAt As Integer
 Dim lThisRow As Integer

    lThisRow = 7

    Do While (Cells(lThisRow, 1) <> "")

        'Range("B7").Select 'This is where picture will be inserted
        pasteAt = Cells(lThisRow, 2)
      '  Cells(pasteAt, 2).Select 'This is where picture will be inserted (IS THIS A DUPLICATE OF ABOVE?)

        'Dim picname As String
        'picname = Range("A7") 'This is the picture name
         picname = Cells(lThisRow, 1) 'This is the picture name

        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("smb://pnld-svr-02._smb._tcp.local/Business Administration/Staff Folders/Ida Moe Evensen/0000 Templates/Pictures/" & picname & ".jpg").Select 'Path to where pictures are stored
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' This resizes the picture
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        With Selection
            '.Left = Range("A6").Left
            '.Top = Range("A6").Top
            .Left = Cells(pasteAt, 1).Left
            .Top = Cells(pasteAt, 1).Top

            .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .ShapeRange.Height = 100#
            .ShapeRange.Width = 80#
            .ShapeRange.Rotation = 0#
        End With

        lThisRow = lThisRow + 11

    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub

ErrNoPhoto:
    MsgBox "Unable to Find Photo" 'Shows message box if picture not found
    Exit Sub


End Sub
```

Comment: I just had a very similar case here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36459111/click-shape-or-button-preview-close-that-displays-an-image/36461010#36461010 I think this will be very helpful for you. BTW: what is your question? Is your code running or do you get an error and it does not complete? Or maybe the result of what your code does is unexpected? In that case, please elaborate what you want it to do and what it currently does.

Comment: Thanks Ralph, I've edited my post so hopefully it is more clear. As you can see my worksheet is not the easiest. But for now, I haven't managed to add/link any image at all.